# D3DXCreateTextureFromFileEx Always Fails

Tags: c++, directx

I'm trying to initialize a sprite in DirectX but D3DXCreateTextureFromFileEx function keeps failing.

```
bool InitSprite(int width, int heigth)
{
imagepos.x = 100;
imagepos.y = 200;
imagepos.z = 0;

if (!SUCCEEDED(D3DXCreateTextureFromFileEx(p_Device, "wood", width, heigth, D3DX_DEFAULT, 0, D3DFMT_UNKNOWN, D3DPOOL_MANAGED,
    D3DX_DEFAULT, D3DX_DEFAULT, 0, NULL, NULL, &p_Texture)))
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "ERROR1", NULL, NULL);
    return false;
}

if (!SUCCEEDED(D3DXCreateSprite(p_Device, &sprite)))
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "ERROR2", NULL, NULL);
    return false;
}

return true;
}
```

ERROR1 box always pops up.
I have the wood image in the C:\ProgramName\Debug folder. I tried directly linking the path C:\Users\UserName\source\repos\ProgramName\Debug\wood but it didn't work.

Comment: you have not specified extension of that image file. You should specify it's extension too

Comment: Change your call to HRESULT hr = D3DXCreateTextureFromFileEx(...); if(FAILED(hr)) { char buf[1024]; sprintf(buf(buf, "Failed to create texture: %#x", hr); MessageBoxA(nullptr, buf, "Error", MB_OK; } and determine what error you get.

Comment: The error I got is D3DXERR_INVALIDDATA. I'll look around to see if I can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, had to use D3DPOOL_DEFAULT parameter.